# I need to make a slider using jquery to show the corresponding text of an image on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the `html` code

```
<div id="slider" class="images">
    <img src="img/image1.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>    
    <img src="img/image2.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image2 corresponding text here</p>    
    <img src="img/image3.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image3 corresponding text here</p>    
</div>
<div class="switch_image">
    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Anybody help me to done this job?Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: How much do you pay per hour?

Comment: @jonathan de M not yet. any suggetion from you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can use the jquery cycle plugin to solve the problem.**

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html.

Comment: i check that you suggest. but they show only the image not the corresponding text that is closest to the image.

Answer (score 3):

This is something for you to implement your own code for sliding.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7k7N/)

**html**

```
<div id="slider" class="images">
<img src="img/image1.png" class="active item" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>    
<img src="img/image2.png" class="item" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image2 corresponding text here</p>    
<img src="img/image3.png" class="item" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image3 corresponding text here</p>    
</div>
<div class="switch_image">
    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#slider img { display: none; }

#slider img + p { display: none; }

#slider img:first-child { display: block; }

#slider img:first-child + p { display: block; }
```

**jquery**

```
$("#next").click(function(){
slideImage(); 
 });

 function slideImage(dir){
   if($("img.active").next().next().hasClass("item"))
       {
         $("img.active").hide().next().hide();
         $("img.active").removeClass("active").next().next().addClass("active");
       }
       else
       {
         $("img.active").removeClass("active").hide().next().hide();
         $("#slider img:first-child").addClass("active");
       }

      $("img.active").show();
     $("img.active").next().show();
 }
```

**Note:** only `next` functionality is implemented

Comment: thanks for your hard works..?